# List comprehension to get multiple values from each tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have a list of tuples like this:

```
myList = [(1,2,3), ('a','b','c'), (4,'j',9)]
```

What I want to do is create a list that has the second and third items (but not the first) of each tuple.

```
[2, 3, 'b', 'c', 'j', 9]
```

Obviously I could do it like this:

```
result = []
for i in myList:
    result.append(i[1])
    result.append(i[2])
```

However, I'd like to know how to do this in a single line with list comprehension.

One thing I attempted to do was:

```
[*(i[1],i[2]) for i in myList]
```

This however didn't work, since Python does not like unpacking in list comprehensions.

Comment: Result should like `[(2, 3), ('b', 'c'), ('j', 9)]`

Comment: @Aran-Fey Sorry, added the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really could do it with a list comprehension:

```
[item for subTuple in myList for item in subTuple[1:]]
```

Understanding:

```
for subTuple in myList:        # Every tuple in the list
    for item in subTuple[1:]:  # Every item starting from index 1
        item                   # the item
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use  [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with list-comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

myList = [(1,2,3), ('a','b','c'), (4,'j',9)]

print(list(chain.from_iterable([(y, z) for _, y, z in myList])))
# [2, 3, 'b', 'c', 'j', 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
from itertools import chain
a = [i[1:3] for i in myList]  
list(chain(*a))
```

Output:   `[2, 3, 'b', 'c', 'j', 9]`